How can I prettify the view-source of a next-js application?
I noticed numerous applications online where the view-source was appropriately formatted and aligned. But I can't get the prettified view-source in Next.js. Though it does not default to the specified prettified format in next-js. I've uploaded the view source of a famous application, as well as my application.
How can we do this? With the use of any third-party plugins?
Prettified view: wikipedia
Next-js
How can I get the view-source to be properly formatted?
